# query not called when props are changed in Apollo client with react js

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I need a query to be called when props are updated in redux store. But it is not happening like that, query is called only once when component is loaded.

My code is like this - -

```
  const sampleData = compose(graphql(ITEMS_BY_CATEGORY, {name:"itemByCategory", options: (props) => ({variables: {_id:props.user._id,searchstring:"", start:0,limit:10, itemype:"created",categoryid:props.categoryid}})}))(samplePage)

export default connect(
  (state) => ({user: state.user.user,categoryid: state.item.categoryid}),
  {}
)(sampleData);
```

I tried refetch method after props are updated. Like  - this.props.data.refetch(). But it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add `componentWillReceiveProps()` and call the query there. It will run whenever the component receives new props. If you need to re-run the `render` function with the results of the query, you may need to call `forceUpdate();`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       const localThis = this;  
       this.client.query({
            query: MY_QUERY,
            variables: {myVar: theVar},
        }).then((result) => {
            localThis.setState({myStateVar: result.data.relevantData});
            localThis.forceUpdate();
        });
  }
```